# Order of Fields in Mongo Query vs Ordered Checked In

Tags: mongodb

Say you're querying documents based on 2 data points. One is a simple bool parameter, and the other is a complicated $geoWithin calculation.

```
db.collection.find( {"geoField": { "$geoWithin" : ...}, "boolField" : true} )
```

Will mongo reorder these parameters, so that it checks the boolField 1st, before running the complicated check?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses indexes like any other DBs. So the important thing for mongoDB is if any query fields has an index or not, not the order of query fields. At least there is no information in their documentation that mongoDB try to checks primitive query fields first. So for your example if `boolField` has an index mongoDB first check this field and eliminate documents whose boolField is false. But If `geoField` has an index then mongoDB first execute query on this field.

So what happens if none of them have index or both of them have? It should be the given order of fields in query because there is no suggestion or info beside of indexes in [query optimization page of mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/). Additionally you can always test your queries performances with just adding `.explain("executionStats")`.

So check the performance of `db.collection.find( {"geoField": { "$geoWithin" : ...}, "boolField" : true} )` and `db.collection.find( { "boolField" : true, "geoField": { "$geoWithin" : ...} } )`. And let us know :)

Answer (score 0):

To add to above response, if you want mongo to use specific index you can use cursor.hint . This https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/ explains how default index selection is done.